# scroll down page in center automatically and freeze

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I have a [blogger page](http://faltovideo.blogspot.com/p/dm_4318.html?id=3806213) where I call another site page on my page:

Now I want this page automatically scroll down and freeze. So, no more scrolling, [like this](http://postimg.org/image/p46hgn0zp).

Comment: What do you mean with _freeze_? User should not be able to scroll?

Comment: If so, you could disable the default behaviour of scrolling `$(document).scroll(function(e){e.preventDefault();});` That isn't recommended ! As long as the scroll bar is visible, the user may attemp to scroll. If you want to display just a part of the linked page, you can `.load()` only a part of a page http://api.jquery.com/load/ . See "loading page fragment"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Looks like you're doing a bad thing there...

Comment: No need to prevent user from scrolling, answer is simple in HTML and CSS, see my answer below. Regardless if user appears to be doing something "bad", this is a handy code snippet. You should however, get permission before embedding other site's content into yours.

Comment: Preventing a user from scrolling isn't very user friendly - do you mean simply scroll to a given point when a given event happens?
Example, user clicks "download" and page scrolls to the download link..

The only part I don't understand is "freeze".

Comment: my problem is when i open it on different browser or cell phone browser, the embed page position changed due to resolution or maybe some other reasons. i want embed page static position for all browser (PC,Cell Phones,Tables etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you were loading this in an iframe, you can turn off scrolling within your iframe, that will answer 1 part of your question.

To load the content of the iframe at a specific position you can use CSS to position the loaded page within your iframe. Something like this should do the job.

```
<style type="text/css">
#outerdiv {
width:446px;
height:246px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}

#inneriframe {
position:absolute;
top:-412px;
left:-318px;
width:1280px;
height:1200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='outerdiv'>
<iframe src="http://somesite.com/" id='inneriframe' scrolling=no></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: please where i add this because i am biggner. In detail please tell what exact i do for this.<object id='php' type="text/html" data="http://fzmoviez.in/video/view/6322662" style="width:700px; height:350px;"></object>

Comment: My code applies to an iframe, it make work for an object as well, give it a shot. You should take some time and learn how to apply styles to your webpage, I don't like to make a habit out of posting cut and paste answers, my example should be enough for you to get started.

Comment: hello sir, as you guide me i was made but here is another problem i face now. if I open link on google chorme browser it shown Download like, but if i open link in internet explorer or my cell phone browser or any other browser, the download hide cause of embeded page position change.

Comment: you might be able to take into account what type of platform is accessing the page using javascript to get the user-agent and information.  You could then set the width and height as variables based on the user agent.